# Можно ли использовать оператор if в таком варианте программы?

Tags: c++

```
        char klas[4];
    {
    if(klas=="231")
    {
    ifstream file ("G:\\1\\ЛР1-231.txt");
        if (file.is_open()) // вызов метода is_open()
    cout << "\n\t Все ОК! Файл открыт!\n\n" << endl;
    else
    {
    cout << "\n\t Файл не открыт!\n\n" << endl;
    return -1;
    }

    fstream inOut  ("G:\\1\\ЛР1-231.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::app);     
    //Открыли для чтения и записи   if(klas=="231")
            if (inOut) {        //Если файл существует, то
       inOut <<"\n" <<"  "<<fam <<" "" \t "<<im<<"   "" \t "<<ot<<" "" \t " 
    <<klas<<" - класс "<<"  "<<"Оценка  -  "<<A0 <<"    "<< now->tm_mday << 
    '-'
     << (now->tm_mon + 1) << '-'
     <<(now->tm_year + 1900)<< endl;    
    }
    file.close();cout << "\n\t Все ОК! Файл закрыт!\n\n" << endl;
    cin.get();
    system("chcp 1251>nul");
    system("color 1f");
    std::string s;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    // читаем файл в контейнер построчно
    std::ifstream in_file("G:\\1\\ЛР1-231.txt", std::ios::in);//"r+",
    while(getline(in_file, s))
    lines.push_back(s);
    in_file.close();

    std::sort(lines.begin(), lines.end()); // сортируем контейнер

    // и записываем отсортированный контейнер в новый файл
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = lines.begin();
    std::ofstream out_file("G:\\1\\ЛР1-231.txt", std::ios::out);//"r+",
    for(; i != lines.end(); ++i)
    out_file << *i << std::endl;
    out_file.close();
    return 0;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Как определили, что не производится? Что именно не производится - запись или сортировка? Ошибка есть? Какая?

Comment: Не производится открытие и запись в текстовый файл

Comment: Открытие? Или запись? Это разные вещи. Открывается ли файл, если название сделать без кириллицы? Чем больше полезной (и меньше ненужной) информации вы дадите, тем больше вероятность получения нужного вам ответа.

Comment: Если смотреть по изменениям текстового файла, то не происходит открытие...

Comment: Ошибок в программе не выдается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл держится открытым так как `inOut` не закрывается. Соответственно `out_file` не открывается. Следует всегда проверять результат либо включать исключения и ограничивать область видимости переменных. Ну и вообще непонятно, зачем тут переоткрывать один и тот же файл четыре раза.

Comment: Почему то мне кажется вопрос весь упирается в оператор  if(klas=="231"), т.к. проверяя на фрагменте программы он или не воспринимается или программа его не видит

Comment: @igorekvp, потому что строки в C нельзя так сравнивать. Для этого используйте `strcmp`.

Comment: Но, strcmp производит сравнение двух назовем данных, а у меня массив klas (4) вводится в самом начале программы и не меняется, так с чем его сравнивать?